# PCA regression coefficients recovery

Tags: generalized-linear-model, pca, linear-model

Assume we have a simple linear model $$y = b^TX + \epsilon$$ for which we want to reduce the number of variables. We perform a PCA reduction on $X$ such that $$Z_{j} = \gamma^{T}_{j}(X-\mu)$$ where the $j$th component of the rotated vector $Z$ is the $j$th principal component of $X$, $\gamma_{j}$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the $j$th ordered eigenvalue and $\mu$ is the mean.

Then, we run a linear regression on $$y=b_{*}^{T}Z + \epsilon$$

Is it possible to recover $b$?

Answer (score 0):

Once you know $b_*^T$, you can get back to $Z$ from $y$.  If you know $Z$, you can get back to $X-\mu$ using the PCSC - principal component score coefficients.  Then add the means, $\mu$ to the feature values.

Comment: This should be, by design, the same vector $b$ that you would have gotten if you fitted the linear model directly, right? We assume here nothing crazy going on with the calibration methods, assume both are OLS.